# Trying to query a range of names in Google Spreadsheets, query is failing with the space in the names

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to query a range of names in Google Spreadsheets. When I try and make a query like: `=QUERY('QA Import'!A1:H, "select A where G = "&B2&"")` where `B2` is `John Doe` I get the error

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROREncountered "Doe" at line 1, column 27. Was expecting one of:  "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "and" ... "or" ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ...

How do I make a query that includes data with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the string value (John Doe) between single quotes ('John Doe'). The resulting formula is:

```
=QUERY('QA Import'!A1:H, "select A where G = '"&B2&"'")
```

**References**

- [QUERY - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [Google Visualization Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)